# YQL geocoding returning different results from different IP's

Tags: geocoding, yql

I'm using yahoo geocoding YQL to get lat/lon for a user-entered location.  The strange thing is that I get different results when querying from different IP addresses.  For example, this query attempts to resolve *London, United Kingdom*:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22london%2C+United+Kingdom%22&appid=my_app_id
```

(before you ask, `my_app_id` is the real ID, which, for obvious reasons, I'm not showing here)

When I run this from my local machine (using `wget` in console), I get valid results.  I get the same results when I run it from our test server.  However when I run it from our live server, I get a different response with `count="0"`.  Because of this, the app is working on my local machine and on our test server, but is failing on the live server.

Something is definitely wrong, but I can't figure out what.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you try encoding the spaces? Instead of +United+Kingdom do %20United%20Kingdom.

Comment: @KaranAshar I don't think this would have any impact.  Copy/paste of the URL works perfectly fine from another server.

Comment: Yea that was a shot in the dark anyways. Will try to check if I see any issue (doesn't seem like it). Just curious, when you say you get different results, does that mean you get different lat/lon values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try adding the Diagnostics option to YQL. That should give you some more insight on the queries that YQL is making on your behalf, and may give a clue.

Here's your query with diagnostics enabled:

[`select * from geo.places where text="london, United Kingdom"`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22london%2C%20United%20Kingdom%22)

With diagnostics on, you can compare your results from your different IPs to track down the difference. If you get a return with zero results, I think it's usually a rate-limit problem.

Comment: Thank god for diagnostic options.  Turns out, yahoo was erroring out because I was exceeding the number of allowed public calls in a given time increment.  Queue a very long debugging/logging/tracing marathon - and it finally came to be that the quota was being exhausted thanks to all the spiders hitting the website (and google is not the worst offender here)...  I now put a workaround and things seem to be slowly getting back to normal.